# Angular 4.3 Http Client

Tags: angular

Please advise how can I replace this existing code I have with new HttpClient with Angular 4.3. My issue is I want to do deep parsing and return typed object outside the service class to Component. The issue is with httpClient I'm not able to return result.data as UserModel

**Old Code**

**Component**

```
 this.loginService.authenticate(this.loginModel).then(
            res => { this.userModel = res;},
            error => { this.handleError(error);}
            );
```

**Service Class**

```
public authenticate(model: LoginModel): Promise<UserModel> {
        return this.http
            .post(this.controller, JSON.stringify(model))
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().result.data as UserModel)
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

**Revised Service Class Code**

```
public authenticate(model: LoginModel): Observable<UserModel> {
            return this.httpClient
                .post<UserModel>(this.controller, model)
                .catch(this.handleError);

        }
```

How do I map response.result.data to Observable and return. I do not want to return complete response object from my class but only part of json as typed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the response using the `map` operator from **rxjs**:

```
public authenticate(model: LoginModel): Observable<UserModel> {
  return this.httpClient
    .post(this.controller, model)
    .map(response => response.result.data as UserModel)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This will return the response data as `UserModel`.

Comment: Editor shows red for response.result.data after map

Comment: Then try  `(response: any) => response.result.data as UserModel`.

Comment: Thank you so much!